# Extended WADL support in Jersey 2 : Injection issue with Provider<SAXParserFactory>

Tags: osgi, guice, jersey-2.0, wadl, hk2

I worked on a web application deployed in an OSGI environment (Equinox). The WAR is deployed in a Jetty 9 Bundle. The application is a JAX RS 2.0 application (Jersey 2) using Guice as injection framework. I use guice bridge to achieve this.

I have a REST resource with WADL comments omitted here :

```
@Context
private Provider<SAXParserFactory> saxFactoryProvider;

@javax.ws.rs.GET
@javax.ws.rs.Produces(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String get() {
    return "Hello REST Guice" + saxFactoryProvider.get();
}
```

This is a test resource to check whether saxFactoryProvider is injected and it is the case, the implementation is org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.SecureSaxParserFactory

With my extended WADL generator configured as follow :

```
@Override
public List<WadlGeneratorDescription> configure() {

    return generator(WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.class).prop(
                "applicationDocsStream", "/application-doc.xml")
            .generator(WadlGeneratorGrammarsSupport.class).prop(
                "grammarsStream", "/application-grammars.xml")
           .generator(WadlGeneratorResourceDocSupport.class).prop(                    "resourceDocStream", "/resourcedoc.xml")

             .descriptions();
}
```

There is a Null pointer exception in the following class because saxFactoryProvider is null even if it is injected the same way a mentioned before :                org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.internal.generators.WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.init(WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc.java:133)

Any idea on the cause ?

Comment: I did a test in Jetty (not a Bundle) and I have the same issue, so ti is not related with OSGI. I then try to deploy a test Jersey 2 application without Guice as IoC framework, but only hk2 and it works. I will focus on hk2 Guice Bridge.

Comment: I did not find how to solve the issue but I finally decided to generate WADL at build time using maven-wadl-plugin.